# Statistical analysis and plotting in pandas (python)

Tags: python, pandas

I have some Capacitance-voltage (also known as C-V) measurement data. They are obtained for various parameters called 'wafer', 'Die', 'ID' etc. I store them in a pandas dataframe.

Now if I apply `df.plot(x='V',y='C')`, I get a plot of all the data without any classification.

How can I efficiently analyze and compare the data for different parameters? For example, I want to compare `C` vs `V` plot-

1. For different wafers
2. For different 'Die' when wafer='D09'
3. For wafer='D10' and G<3 at V=2.5

etc.

```
import pandas as pd

V=[2.5,2,1.5,1,0]
C_1=[5e-6,3e-6,1e-6,0.3e-6,0.1e-6]
G_1=[3e-3,1.2e-3,1e-3,0.8e-3,0.02e-3]

C_2=[5.5e-6,3.5e-6,1.5e-6,0.4e-6,0.3e-6]
G_2=[3.2e-3,1.4e-3,1.5e-3,1.8e-3,0.2e-3]

C_3=[5.3e-6,3.7e-6,1.7e-6,0.6e-6,0.45e-6]
G_3=[5.2e-3,2.4e-3,2.5e-3,2.8e-3,0.25e-3]

C_4=[5.1e-6,6.7e-6,2.7e-6,1.6e-6,1.45e-6]
G_4=[5.3e-3,3.4e-3,1.5e-3,3.8e-3,1.25e-3]


data_1={'Wafer':'D09','ID':'ab','Die':150,'x':6,'y': 15,'V':V,'C':C_1,'G':G_1}
data_2={'Wafer':'D09','ID':'cd','Die':130,'x':10,'y': 15,'V':V,'C':C_2,'G':G_2}
data_3={'Wafer':'D10','ID':'cd','Die':140,'x':4,'y': 15,'V':V,'C':C_3,'G':G_3}
data_4={'Wafer':'D10','ID':'ab','Die':120,'x':12,'y': 15,'V':V,'C':C_4,'G':G_4}

df1=pd.DataFrame(data_1)
df2=pd.DataFrame(data_2)
df3=pd.DataFrame(data_3)
df4=pd.DataFrame(data_4)

df=pd.concat([df1,df2,df3])
```

Comment: You could do a simple condition similar to `newdf=  df[df['Wafer']=='D09']` and easily plot the new `newdf`. Is that what you actually need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do conditions as:

```
new_df_1= df[df['Wafer']=='D09']
new_df_2= df[(df['Wafer']=='D09') & (df['Die']==150)]
new_df_3= df[df['G'] < 3]
new_df_4= df[df['V'] < 2.5]
new_df_5= df[(df['G']== 3) & (df['V'] < 2.5)]
```

and easily plot the new dataframes. 
Is that what you actually need?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The first command (new_df_1) works but the rest don't. I couldn't follow the logic of the braces. Most importantly, defining bunch of new dataframes are not convenient specially when you have large parameter space. I was wondering if there is something easier :(

Comment: @Alam sorry! I did several typo mistakes, but it should work now. Also, you don't have to declare all the datafrales as I did, you can directly `df[df['G'] < 3].plot(x='V',y='C')`